# Shopify JSON data varies depending on how a file is loaded

Tags: json, shopify

I am loading information into shopify metafields for images on a product page. I then have a JSON object that I use to get these images and output them in Alpine JS.

The JSON data looks like this:

```html
image: {{ variant.metafields.variant.image_gallery.value | json }},
```

If I load in the image to the product media area, and then assign it to the metafield object it has all the right data (src, alt, preview_image etc).

However, if I load the image in directly to the Content > files area and then assign it to the metafield from there...

the objects look like this

```html
image: "\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0254\/7220\/4885\/files\/jussioksanen-0937_1.jpg?v=1700687738"
```

instead of like this for the images that are loaded into the product media:

```html
image: {"alt":"A person wearing sunglasses","id":23092239695957,"position":7,"preview_image":{"aspect_ratio":1.0,"height":2000,"width":2000,"src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0254\/7220\/4885\/products\/lens-lifestyle-dark-brown-1_f10983ca-693c-4188-b35d-5b9d5ee3d67b.jpg?v=1694803088"},"aspect_ratio":1.0,"height":2000,"media_type":"image","src":"https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0254\/7220\/4885\/products\/lens-lifestyle-dark-brown-1_f10983ca-693c-4188-b35d-5b9d5ee3d67b.jpg?v=1694803088","width":2000}
```

Does anyone know why this might be??

Answer (score 0):

You have a field of type JSON. If you save JSON in a field of type JSON and then you ask for the value you get JSON. But if you pass it through a filter of JSON then you also get JSON. But if you save JSON as JSON encoded as JSON and just ask for the data, you might just get the string still JSON encoded.

It all boils down to you ensuring you deal with the inconsistencies of JSON in Metafields. You know there are some now, so you code defensively against them. There is nothing wrong in what you're doing, just experiment a little more to reveal where you can just use a value, and where you get a value but pass in through further filtering. And pay attention to what you save as JSON. It can make a difference!